# How to get twitter's direct message conversation threads in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am striving hard to get the threaded conversation list of twitters direct messages. The twitter seems not providing its conversation API publically.

The work around , I was thinking on , is as below:

There are two separate API:

1. GET direct_messages : This api returns all the direct messages sent
   to you.
2. GET direct_messages/sent : This api returns all the direct
       messages sent by you.

I am planning to compare/merge the list based on the sender and receiver id to group them and create conversation threads.
But it is not feasible to mix these two result to get the entire conversation.Because we get 20 to 30 messages per call it might be possible that the entire conversation might not match.

Can anyone suggest or route me to a more precise solution which will provide me with the direct message conversation thread

Comment: I have the same issue Rakesh..if it is fixed for you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages):

> You can request up to 200 direct messages per call, and only the most recent 200 DMs will be available using this endpoint.

Really, the best you can do is take the 200 most recent messages sent to your user.  Then, you can [grab up to 800 messages sent by the user](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages/sent).

You'll have to thread them yourself based on their timestamp.

There's no other way to do this at the moment.

Comment: First of all thanks for confirming the solution. So, I will have to group and create a thread by mapping the sender id in the direct_messages and direct_messages/sent service responses, right? I will be looping the direct_messages/sent service response and will map both the ids  and form the array of groups.

Comment: That's the only sensible way I can think of doing it.

Comment: @RakeshLampStack : Hi, how you are mapping direct_messages/sent service response with ids and forming array group ?

Comment: Sorry for bumping but how do you set it to get 200 messages per call? I use `$twitter->get( "direct_messages", array() )` with [`TwitterOAuth`](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) n it gets me 20 per call @TerenceEden @RakeshLampStack

Comment: As per the documentation - use the `count` parameter.